# CONTRIBUTING.md does not render as a web page on github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

i'm in the process of moving my contributing.md file from the project root to the docs/ directory so it can be with the rest of the documentation. Other markdown files in docs render properly when viewed in github pages. For example, the page

https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/userguide/toc
renders the page toc.md as expected.

however,

https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/contributing

returns a 404, while simply adding the .md extension

https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/contributing.md

returns the page as markdown source

The github project is https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw.
and the contributing.md file is in the docs/ folder.

Comment: Can you add a direct link to your Github repo?

Comment: Also, could you specify whether or not you're using a `/docs` folder or a `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: [`https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/contributing.md`](https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/contributing.md) is accessible though.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, yes, but that's the issue that he describes in his question—he can only see the raw file and not it in the repo

Comment: How I missed that part while reading? 

Comment: I think there might be problem during Page Building.

Comment: @ZacharyEspiritu The github project is https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw 
and the contributing.md file is in the docs/ folder.

Comment: @L.Blanc Thanks!

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov All good :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zachary's answer is correct but there is a way to modify the jekyll's configuration to include the specific page.

Here is an example: https://masterex.github.io/test-docs/contributing

You have to modify `_config.yml` as follows:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-minimal
include: contributing.md
```

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/) is github's relevant help page.

Comment: For newer versions, these now have to be put in an array `include: [ 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'LICENSE.md' ]`

Answer (score 5):

After forking [your repo](https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw), playing around with it for a bit, and banging my head against the wall because I didn't understand why it wasn't working, I realized something:

**Github Pages doesn't support building Jekyll pages from files that have names that Github recognizes for other purposes.** These file names include (in addition to their lowercase versions):

- [`CONTRIBUTING.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-guidelines-for-repository-contributors/)
- [`ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue-template-for-your-repository/)
- [`PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue-template-for-your-repository/)
- [`ISSUE_AND_PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue-template-for-your-repository/)
- [`CODEOWNERS.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/)

On the other hand, despite that `README.md` is also a Github keyword file, it looks like Github Pages supports using files with the `README.md` name because it purposely will interpret them the same way as an `index.md` or `index.html` file. See [this link from the Github blog](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3) for more information.

---

To answer your specific question on how you could get the file to show at the `/tablesaw/contributing` path, you could rename it and move it to the `/docs/contributing/index.md` or `/docs/contributing/README.md` path.

U̶n̶f̶o̶r̶t̶u̶n̶a̶t̶e̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶e̶s̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶k̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶G̶i̶t̶h̶u̶b̶ ̶P̶a̶g̶e̶s̶ ̶b̶u̶i̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶t̶.̶

---

**Edit:** [@Master_ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900131/5099203) notes correctly that you can use the [`include` configuration option](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/) in the `_config.yml` file to include files that would normally be excluded by Github:

```
theme:   jekyll-theme-minimal
include: contributing.md
```

In reference to the original example, this will allow Github Pages to build a page successfully at the `/docs/contributing` path.